# GPS location tracking in .NET

Tags: .net

I want to build a GPS location tracking application in .NET, is there any way/third party dlls that allow to implement gps in .net?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean is there hardware out there that has a .Net library associated with it?  You need specific hardware to work with GPS.

Comment: If it were for some POSIX system, you'd just use `gpsd`... but for Windows I am also interested.

Comment: It is only with Win7 that there's been a standard interface for Windows. Before that you either had to use vendor-specific libraries/apps or program against the NMEA0183 standard. This actually specified serial RS232, so most vendors ship libraries which make their (typically USB based) devices appear to be connected on a COM port.

Answer (score 0):

If you can restrict yourself to Windows 7 (and later) then there's the Location API. Saves the hassle of faffing around with NMEA0183 serial protocols and ensuring the user has set up their virtual serial port properly!

Yes a third party library would solve the protocol 'faff' but you would still have to make sure the user has set their 'port' settings properly.